# Explanation of notation - Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading the following piece of text:

> Let $T: V \to W$ and $S: U \to V$ be two linear transformations between vector spaces $U, V, W$ of finite dimension.
>
> Since $S(U) \subset V, T(S(U)) \subset T(V)$, i.e. $R(T \circ S) \subset R(T)$. So rank$(T \circ S) \leq$ rank$(S)$

What does $R(T)$ signify here? What does the $R$ mean? The row space?

The source of the text: [http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xichen/math22514w/20140212_printable.pdf](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/%7Exichen/math22514w/20140212_printable.pdf)

Section: "Ranks of compositions of linear transformations"

Comment: It could. This is more of a question of how the author defines this. This could be a standard notation that I am not aware of, but in my linear algebra classes, we haven't used $"R(T)"$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From context and common sense I am almost sure that $R(T)$, for example, refers to the range of a linear map $T$.

In Friedberg's linear algebra, for instance, use $N(T)$ to denote the zero set of $T$ and $R(T)$ the range of $T$.

Comment: Range is the image, right?

Comment: More precisely, the image of the domain. :)